# Error: system is running in low-graphics mode

Tags: command-line, drivers, intel-graphics

I installed Ubuntu in my SSD with my desktop and It worked well. Then I put it on my laptop and I got the error system is running in low-graphics mode. The error prompt before I reach the Ubuntu login screen.

My Ubuntu version is 18.04 LTS and my laptop is a Lenovo T470 with an Intel GPU.

I know that this question was asked a lot, but I tried all the answers I saw. Does anyone have a more up-to-date solution and/or related to Intel graphics drivers? The recovery menu failsafeX didn't work either.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you try, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question ([edit]). You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [ask])

Comment: None of the answers work for me. I need a solution specific for Intel GPU and my laptop isn't that old. I would like to be sure there's nothing I can do before installing Lubuntu or Xubuntu.